# NSString get string in middle of String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a bunch of strings, and I want to always get the string inbetween the { and } including the braces. So if I have

```
@"alsdkfj {'asdf':'stuff stuff'} more stuff"
```

I want output

```
@"{'asdf':'stuff stuff'}"
```

How could I do this? The string is always different so I cant just search for "alsdkfj", I need regarless of what it is to get inbetween the {}

Answer (score 2):

You can get multiple subString using following code.

```
  NSString* placeHolderString = @"alsdkfj {'asdf':'stuff stuff'} more stuff";
    NSRegularExpression* faceRegexQuota = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\\{(.*?)\\}" options:0 error:NULL];
    [faceRegexQuota enumerateMatchesInString:placeHolderString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeHolderString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

        NSString* matchText = [placeHolderString substringWithRange:[match range]];
        NSLog(@"Output : %@",matchText);

    }];
```

**Output** :  {'asdf':'stuff stuff'}

Comment: @jamesbrown, let me know if you stuck anywhere.. this is dynamic return number of substring that match with your whole string

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
NSString *finalString = @"alsdkfj {'asdf':'stuff stuff'} more stuff";
NSRange range2 = [content rangeOfString:@"{"];
NSRange range3 = [content rangeOfString:@"}"];
int lengt = range3.location - range2.location - range2.length;
int location = range2.location + range2.length;
NSRange range4;
range4.location = location;
range4.length = lengt;
finalString = [finalString substringWithRange:range4];
finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",finalString];
```

Comment: I want it to include the `{` at the begging in and the `}` at the end

Comment: @jamesbrown Please check the update. You can easily include the braces yourself.